# Getting list of countries, cities and their areas/states/towns respectively

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api, android-spinner

Is this possible to load a list of all countries in a spinner, then on selecting the particular country, all of its cities appears in another spinner and after selecting the city, we get the list of areas or towns of that city in android using google-api or something like country picker?
Currently i am using this to get the list of countries. but how to get their respective cities and towns?

```
    ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
String[] locales = Locale.getISOCountries();
for (String countryCode : locales) {
    Locale obj = new Locale("", countryCode);
    list.add(obj.getDisplayCountry());
}
```

Comment: I do this using two spinners.

Comment: I don't think Google Maps APIs can get a list of all cities in the country. These APIs don't work like database search.

Comment: Note: This question is requesting a recommendation for an API, which is not allowed on Stack Overflow. See the [help/dont-ask].

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the JSON file available [here](https://github.com/David-Haim/CountriesToCitiesJSON/blob/master/countriesToCities.json). Just add it to your project into the `assets` folder and add the list of cities and countries to spinner after parsing it.

Comment: How do you parse this thing?

Comment: check this out for details about JSON parsing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-do-i-parse-json-in-android

Comment: new Gson().fromJson(getContentFromCountryFile(), new TypeToken<Map<String, List<String>>>() {
            }.getType())    
If someone else is trying to solve it. Just put this dependency in the gradle:
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'