# Retrieve cities list of a country

Tags: python, geolocation, overpass-api, geonames

Which is the best api to retrieve all the cities in given country?
I tried downloading from geonames. but it seems data is not reliable.`
Is it possible to query city, along with state and country in overpass api?

Can you please suggest a better way to download cities and its points?

Comment: If you have not done it already, I recommend searching and posting the question on the GIS site: https://gis.stackexchange.com.  OSM also has its own help forum with similar questions like this one: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/13877/how-to-find-cities-and-states-using-osm-overpass-api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done a similar task by making use of [overpass api](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) with the help of [overpy](https://python-overpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html#installation) which is a python package.

Firstly I have retrieved all states of country using the query

```
    [out:json];
    area["ISO3166-1"="IN"];
    (rel(area)["admin_level"="4"];);
    out;
```

Now I have fetched all districts for each state which is `admin_level=5`.

```
    [out:json];
    area["ISO3166-2"="IN-KL"];
    (rel(area)["admin_level"="5"];);
    out;
```

State `ISO3166-2`is from the data received from the API.
Now you can fetch cities for each districts using the data from API.

```
    [out:json];
    area["ISO3166-2"="{0}"]["admin_level"="4"];
    (rel["name"="Thiruvananthapuram"](area);)->.center;
    node(around.center:10000)["place"];
    out;"""
```

This worked for me. 
Remember fetching all the cities in a country is a really huge task for the OSM Servers. Fetch the data that you really need.

Answer (score 1):

if you are specific to the name of the cites or state or country then u can use this API.
https://pypi.org/project/geosky/

This API is having a record of all countries, states, and cities. Here is the sample code...

```
from geosky import geo_plug

geo_plug.all_CountryNames()

geo_plug.all_Country_StateNames()

geo_plug.all_State_CityNames(name)# name == 'all' or state name
geo_plug.all_State_CityNames('Odisha')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are searching for APIs to get a list of countries and a list of cites of a particular country, then try https://github.com/shivammathur/countrycity

1. You can simply GET `https://shivammathur.com/countrycity/countries` to get a list of all countries.
2. `https://shivammathur.com/countrycity/countries/ind` to get only
   counties having "ind" in them.
3. `https://shivammathur.com/countrycity/cities/India` to get all cities of India.
4. You may face a CORS issue for the above-mentioned URLs for use in frontend applications, in that case, please try https://countrystatecity.in/ . For which you can get an API key in a day by filling up a google form.

Or if you are looking for JSON holding this data, please refer to:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40798401/16087692

Answer (score 0):

I will answer your second question regarding Overpass API.  You can query cities for a particular country using that API.  Just to demonstrate its capabilities, there is a web-based query tool for OSM called Overpass Turbo (http://overpass-turbo.eu) where you can submit queries and display and download data.  The following query will provide all cities in the United States, for example:

```
{{geocodeArea:"United States"}}->.searchArea;
(
  node["place"="city"](area.searchArea);
);
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

The query will return the following:

[image]

Per [OSM Wiki](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:place%3Dcity), the "city" tag is used "to identify the largest settlement or settlements within a territory, including national, state, and provincial capitals, and other major conurbations."  On the same Wiki page, there is a note about differentiating between cities and towns.  In the above query, "city" can be replaced with "town".  Other possible values (including country and state) are listed here: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:place#Values

If you are looking to obtain city-to-state relationships from the data, you may not always get reliable results.  For example, you may get the following detailed GeoJSON entry for Duluth, MN:

```
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "@id": "node/19188464",
        "is_in": "Minnesota USA",
        "is_in:continent": "North America",
        "is_in:country": "USA",
        "is_in:country_code": "US",
        "is_in:state": "Minnesota",
        "name": "Duluth",
        "name:ja": "ãƒ€ãƒ«ãƒ¼ã‚¹",
        "name:oj": "Onigamiinsing",
        "name:ru": "Ð”ÑƒÐ»ÑƒÑ‚",
        "place": "city",
        "population": "86265",
        "population:source": "2010",
        "wikidata": "Q485708",
        "wikipedia": "en:Duluth, Minnesota"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -92.1251218,
          46.7729322
        ]
      },
      "id": "node/19188464"
    },
```

but only the following entry for Madison, WI:

```
{
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "@id": "node/29941752",
        "alt_name:ru": "ÐœÑÐ´Ð¸ÑÐ¾Ð½",
        "capital": "4",
        "is_in:continent": "North America",
        "is_in:country": "USA",
        "name": "Madison",
        "name:en": "Madison",
        "name:pl": "Madison",
        "name:ru": "ÐœÐ°Ð´Ð¸ÑÐ¾Ð½",
        "name:ta": "à®®à¯‡à®Ÿà®¿à®šà®©à¯",
        "name:uk": "ÐœÐµÐ´Ñ–ÑÐ¾Ð½",
        "place": "city",
        "population": "243344",
        "state_capital": "yes",
        "website": "http://www.cityofmadison.com/",
        "wikidata": "Q43788",
        "wikipedia": "en:Madison, Wisconsin"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -89.3837613,
          43.074761
        ]
      },
      "id": "node/29941752"
    },
```

Comment: One line to emphasize here is the one with `>` ... this so-called recursion makes the syntax pretty concise.